# Angular: How to handle foreign keys in arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, foreign-keys, in-memory-database, angular-observable

I have a class `meal` and `mealplan`. Each mealplan has an Array of five foreign keys, referring to meal  objects.

```
export class Meal {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export class Mealplan {
  id: number;
  mealsPerWeek: Meals[] = new Array(5);
}
```

all datas are stored in the in-memory-data-service from Angular like this:

```
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const meals = [
      {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Meal 1',
        price: 18.00,
      },
      {
        id: 102,
        name: 'Meal 2',
        price: 20.00,
      },
    ]; 
    const mensaplan = [
      {id: 1, mealsPerWeek: [101, 102, 103, 104, 105]},
      {id: 2, mealsPerWeek: [105, 104, 103, 102, 101]}
    ];

return {meal, mealplan};
```

**Mensaplan.service.ts:**

```
export class MealPlanService {

  private mealplanUrl = 'api/meaplan';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getMealplan(): Observable<Mealplan[]> {
    return this.http.get<Mealplan[]>(this.mealplanUrl)
  }
}
```

**mealplan.component.ts**

```
 getMealplan(): void {
   this.mealplanService.getMealplan()
     .subscribe(mealplan => this.mealplan = mealplan);
 }
}
```

If I render it now in the template with `{{mealplan.mealsPerWeek}}` I only get the Array `101,102,103,104,105`.

What is the best way to handle the Array of IDs to display the properties of the class `meal`

The result should be something like

MealPerWeek: Meal 1 (Price), Meal 2 (Price), etc.

Comment: This is not clear. Those aren't FKs; a FK is a set of relation/table attributes/columns whose subtuple/subrow values appear elsewhere as CK (in the relational model) or as UNIQUE (in SQL), or we say FK (value) when we mean such a subtuple/subrow value. "handle" & "display the properties" are unclear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: @philipxy with FK I wanted to express that a class has the ID's of Objects from another class in it. Afterwards I want to use the IDs to get other properties of this Object

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please ask 1 clear specific non-duplicate question. PS "use the IDs to get other properties" is still vague. Say what the code you are trying to write is supposed to accomplish & what it expects as input.

Answer (score 0):

use Map instead of Object for example:
It will easy to iterate and fetch values of meal

```js
const meals =  new Map([
  [101, {name:'Meal 1',price:18.00}],
  [102, {name:'Meal 2',price:20.00}],
  [103, {name:'Meal 3',price:17.00}],
  [104, {name:'Meal 4',price:22.00}],
  [105, {name:'Meal 5',price:17.00}],
  [106, {name:'Meal 6',price:29.00}],
]);
    const mensaplan = [
      {id: 1, mealsPerWeek: [101, 102, 103, 104, 105]},
      {id: 2, mealsPerWeek: [105, 104, 103, 102, 101]}
    ];


function greeter(plan) {
let val = "";
for(let i=0;i<plan.length;i++){
const name = meals.get(plan[i].mealsPerWeek[0]).name;
const price = meals.get(plan[i].mealsPerWeek[0]).price;
val +='Meal ID '+plan[i].id+'meals name '+name+' price '+price+'<br>';
}
 return val;
}


document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = greeter(mensaplan);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: How do I declare the class properties with your solution? is it still "export class Meal"? I am having a hard time with changing a class into a map.

Comment: What is the purpose of Class creation.If this only to check type use interface simplly return from the api.
return ObjectVal from the api.

`interface MealPlan {
    name: String,
    id: Number,
    MealsData?: Object,
    
}
const meals =  new Map([
  [101, {name:'Meal 1',price:18.00}],
  [102, {name:'Meal 2',price:20.00}],
  [103, {name:'Meal 3',price:17.00}],
  [104, {name:'Meal 4',price:22.00}],
  [105, {name:'Meal 5',price:17.00}],
  [106, {name:'Meal 6',price:29.00}],
]);
const ObjectVal: MealPlan[] = [{
    name: 'Meal',
    id: 101,
    MealsData:meals
}] `